# My filter function is not registering anything with a & in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have created a simple program that filters words based on a list from an external txt file with regex inside my js file.

For the most part when I input a list of words from the txt file they are filtered out. However there is one keyword that is causing me trouble.

'black & decker'

I am guessing it has to do with the '&' sign because any new words I put into the txt file with a '&' sign does not filter out for some reason.

Can anyone help me to why words with the & is not filtering out properly? And also check if my regex is written properly for this program(var filtered)?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

I have a list of words in a txt file here:

```
baby bullet, baby-bullet, back2life, back-2-life, black & decker, black-decker, black-&-decker, britax, bose, capital brands products, capital-brands-products, dewalt, dyson, ergobaby, ergo-baby, fiskars, ickle bubba, ickle-bubba, kitchen aid, kitchen-aid, longstem, long-stem, magic bullet, magic-bullet, makita tools, makita-tools, milwaukee, monster cable, monster-cable, mustee, nest, nutri____, nutribullet, oxo, party bullet, shark, simplehuman, sony bravia, urban decay, urban-decay, waterpik, weber grill, weber-grill, youthology, teeter
```

Here is my JS file that filters inputted words based on the txt list

```
 // This grabs the data from the txt file and splits each word by commas
 $.get('word-list.txt', function(data) {
    pbfFilterWords = data.split(', ');
    pbfFilterWords.forEach(function(word){
    pbfWordList = word;
 });

 // This defines a global variable so the filter button has a list of words to filter with
 var pbfWordList = pbfFilterWords;

 //This will allow the list of words to filter with regex
 var pbfRegEx = pbfFilterWords;

 var filtered = (function(){
     var filtered = [], i = pbfRegEx.length;
     while (i--) {
         if (/w*[\s|\w|\b+]*\w*/.test(pbfRegEx[i])) {
             filtered.push(pbfRegEx[i]);
         }
     }
     return filtered;
 })();
 console.log(filtered.join());

 // Function for filter button
 $('.pbf-link-container[contenteditable]').html;
 $('#pbf-filter').click(function(){
        var $pbfOutput = $('.pbf-link-container[contenteditable]').html();
        // Array of words for filter
        var pbfFilterWords = pbfWordList;
            // Output to new DIV and remove specified keywords from pbfFilterWords
            $('.pbf-link-output').html($pbfOutput);
            // To make pbfFilterWords not case sensitive
            $.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
                return function( elem ) {
                return $(elem).html().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
                    };
            });
            // Function to output the filtered words
            $.each(pbfFilterWords , function(i , filtered){
            $('.pbf-link-output > div:contains("'+filtered+'")').remove();
        });
    });
});
```

Here is my html:

```
<div id="pbf-container">
    .....
        <div class="pbf-link-container" contenteditable="true">
        <div><br/></div>
        </div>
            <div class="pbf-button-control">
                <button id="pbf-filter"> Filter </button>
            </div>
                    <div class="pbf-filter-header">
                        <h3> Filtered Links </h3>
                    </div>
                <div class="pbf-link-output">
                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what are you trying to filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pseudo selector implementation takes html version of inner contents of the div tag, so it converts `&` to `&AMP;` and you don't have a match.

You can see yourself:

```
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
  return function( elem ) {
    // console.log value of current element here
    console.log($(elem).html().toUpperCase()); // logs string with &AMP;
    return $(elem).html().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
  };
});
```

use `$(elem).text()` to get text version of inner content of a div.

Comment: ahh, I see, thank you for pointing that out. If I were to change the contenteditable to a <form> instead, do you think it will also fix this?

Comment: I don't think so, since html() still would convert special symbols to their html code representations. I think text() here would be a solution.

Comment: Got it, Thank you for the help. I switched the (elem) to .text () and it is working now :). Thank you.

Comment: @Publifiedlabs and, btw, `/w*[\s|\w|\b+]*\w*/.test(pbfRegEx[i])` - is this intended to make sure that filter words in txt file are in proper format? if so, then 1) you don't use the filtered list (`filtered` variable) in `$.each(pbfFilterWords` 2) current reg exp doesn't match "black & decker" if reg exp would search from beginning (^) to the end ($) of the string (`/^w*[\s|\w|\b+]*\w*$/`) - probably you could just list allowed characters here with `/^[a-z\d\s\-_&]*$/i` if the filter line format is not important.